# Quadratic Residue of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Prove that if $p$ is prime, then:

$F_p = (\frac{5}{p})$ mod $p$.

I tried finding residues $(\frac{5}{p}) $ in the sequence, but I haven't found anything. I have no idea how to utilize the sequence. Maybe there is a connection with Binet's Formula?

Comment: The key parts of the argument are given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2539028/11619), so I will close this as a duplicate. All, please comment, if you disagree with my duplicate target. There may be a better one. I figured out the answer myself, and realized that we must have done this already. Sure enough, a moment's search came up with that oldie.

Comment: Anyway, SuperMage, your hunch is correct, the (algebraic) conjugacy in Binet's formula leads to the answer. Qiaochu Yuan's answer requires a bit of familiarity with the Galois theory of finite fields. Have you seen that piece of algebra? If not, then we may need to add something. All material on Pisano periods will help you here (modulo $p$ the Fibonacci sequence repeats with a period that is a factor of either $p-1$ or $2(p+1)$ according to whether $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ or not.

Comment: Sorry, I not learned anything in galois theory or anything like that. I found this problem on a number theory file https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/SatoNT.pdf
I was hoping to get a nice solution using elementary number theory

Comment: SuperMage1, are you familiar with the congruence $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p\pmod p$? That leads to a solution along the following lines. 1st observe that because $5^{(p-1)/2}\equiv\left(\dfrac 5p\right)\pmod p$ we have
$$(b\sqrt5)^p\equiv\left(\frac5p\right) b\sqrt5,$$ and then
$$(a+b\sqrt5)^p\equiv a+\left(\frac5p\right) b\sqrt5,$$ both congruences modulo $p$. With these observations the congruences in Qiaochu's answer hopefully begin to make sense?

Comment: (cont'd) If $5$ is quadratic residue then $(a+b\sqrt5)^p\equiv a+b\sqrt 5$. If it is a quadratic non-residue, then $(a+b\sqrt5)^p\equiv a-b\sqrt5$. Therefore raising to $p$th power has the effect indicated in that answer.

Comment: See also [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h140331p793709).